# Viber bot. Запуск на localhost

Tags: node.js, localhost, express, viber

Пытаюсь потестить Viber бота. В последствии планируется создание бота для Viber и Telegram. но для начала интересен только Viber. 
Пользуюсь фреймворком [Bottender](https://bottender.js.org/), потому что, повторюсь, планируется создание для нескольких мессенджеров.
Итак, консольно все получается без проблем, но вот на счет потестить "в мессенджере" есть проблемы, скорее из-за непонимания происходящего. Я, как и указано, создаю public account, получаю уникальный ключ и запускаю и ничего не получаю. Запускаю на localhost и ловлю "Cannot GET /". В принципе, все ясно - нет же вьюхи, которую могу просмотреть. Если пользоваться туториалом на [Viber документации](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/nodejs-bot-api/), то получаю тоже самое.
Пользуюсь nodejs ( express ).

Так вот вопрос, как же потестить бота локально?
Может есть какой-то вариант, который уже проверен?

Comment: [Test Your Bots Locally with Ngrok](https://developers.viber.com/blog/2017/05/24/test-your-bots-locally)

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Это невозможно.

Бот сможет отправлять сообщения только после того, как ему скормят вебхук, а работоспособность вебхука Вайбер проверяет, отправляя по указанному адресу POST-запрос и ожидает на него ответ. Если ответа нет - бот на отправку сообщений не активируется.

Comment: За Вайбер не скажу, поскольку не пробовал, но бота для Телеги писал и тестил у себя на локалхосте без проблем. На серваке который скармливал под вебхук при помощи NGinx-проксирования и имеющегося там OpenVPN переадресовывал на комп с поднятым OpenServer. А ещё до этого у меня был белый IP,... если есть таковой, то какие проблемы?